# Iterating over an array in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, rpm

I want to write code that reads a list of packages from an array
and tells me whether the corresponding RPM is installed:

```
ARRAY=(
pkg-config
python
python-devel
python-libs
readline
renderproto
sqlite
tcl
tk
zlib
)

for i in `echo  ${ARRAY[@]}`
do
    rpm -q $i
done
```

This code doesn't work properly. I want the output to be `ok rpm named
foobar is installed` or `rpm named foobar is not installed`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `rpm` appears to change its exit status depending on
whether the queried package is installed, so it can be used by `if`:

```
for package in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    if rpm -q $package >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
       echo "Package $package is installed."
    else
       echo "Package $package is not installed."
    fi
done
```

Comment: Works fine,a suggestion only 2>&1 >/dev/null is better than two > >